# How to select a specific row from a set of rows in SQL

Tags: sql, datetime, subquery, snowflake-cloud-data-platform, hierarchical-data

I need to select a specific row from a "set" of a admission data. It took me some time to try and understand the process and I'll try to explain what I need to achieve with an example.

So, below, I have a history of admission and readmissions to a hospital for a specific member. We can classify the below rows in the image as different admission sets.

Every new admission is given a `CLM_NBR` and if the member is re-admitted, for some reasons, as a follow-up to the previous admission, the `READMIT_CLM_NBR` of the initial admission/re-admission is equal to the `CLM_NBR` of the new, related re-admission. We call the very first admission of a set the original admission.

If an admission does not have a re-admission, the `READMIT_CLM_NBR` will be `NULL`.

The admission sets are as follows:

***admission set 1*** : Row number 4

***admission set 2*** : Row number 6, 7, 8

***admission set 3*** : Row number 5, 1, 3, 2

[image]

Now, I need to get the `DATE_ADMITTED` of the original admission in the last admission set (admission set 3). The highlighted row is the one that we need and a query should return `2016-05-18` as the value. I'm trying to figure out a way of partitioning or grouping by the dates but nothing seems to work.

Since we care only if there was a corresponding re-admission, all rows with NULL `READMIT_CML_NBR` can be discarded. The query should look like:

```
select READMIT_CLM_NBR, CLM_NBR, DATE_ADMITTED 
from P_Admission 
where READMIT_CLM_NBR in (select distinct CLM_NBR from P_Admission) and MBR_ID = '0610297305';
```

the query then returns the following result...

[image]2

I need to get the date from the highlighted row. Any ideas on how this can be done?

Comment: Accepted one of the answers as a solution. Both are correct now! Thank you for the reminder

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be able to get the result you want by finding all `CLM_NBR` values that are not also a `READMIT_CLM_NBR` (so they are the original admission); these rows can then be ordered by `DATE_ADMITTED` and the row with the latest date selected:

```
WITH CTE AS (
    SELECT READMIT_CLM_NBR, CLM_NBR, DATE_ADMITTED,
           ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY DATE_ADMITTED DESC) AS rn
    FROM P_Admission p1
    WHERE MBR_ID = '0610297305'
      AND NOT EXISTS (SELECT * FROM P_Admission p2 WHERE p2.READMIT_CLM_NBR = p1.CLM_NBR)
) 
SELECT READMIT_CLM_NBR, CLM_NBR, DATE_ADMITTED
FROM CTE
WHERE rn = 1
```

Demo (for MySQL 8 but generic SQL) [on db-fiddle](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/3YHUK2t8DXGZ23iwuwuuA/0)

Answer (score 1):

If I am following this correctly, you can use `not exists`:

```
select max(date_admitee)
from p_admission pa
where 
    mbr_id = '0610297305'
    and readmit_clm_nbr is not null
    and not exists (
        select 1
        from p_admission pa1
        where pa1.readmit_clm_nbr = pa.clm_nbr
    )
```

Comment: This query does not return the proper date, unfortunately. It's returning 2016-03-23 instead of 2016-05-18.

Comment: @ElDj: that would be surprising. 2016-03-23 has a `null` value in  `readmit_clm_nbr`, and the query specifically filters out such row.

Comment: You are correct. The query returns null. The query should be working i think.  https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/rVd983F961GvDi971XD55j/2

Comment: @ElDj: the columns were inverted in the `where` clause of the subquery. Fixed.